# qpython hello world not working

Tags: qpython

I'm new to qpython (obviously :P ) 
I was trying the helloworld.py that's built in to the qpython app
From what I gather, it should pop up a text box to collect a name and open a window with "Hello, "
The first part works. it collects the name, but the maketoast(s) is not working. what is wrong?

this was on Nexus 5 running android 5.1.2

Added source code below as suggested:

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:console
#qpy:2
import androidhelper
droid = androidhelper.Android()
line = droid.dialogGetInput()
s = "Hello, %s" % (line.result)
print s
droid.makeToast(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post what the code is?
For mine to do that I edited it to say:

```
import sl4a
droid = sl4a.Android()
name = input('What is your name?: ') 
droid.makeToast('Hello,' + name)
print('Hello ' + name)
```